# Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager for ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

How do I inject RoleManager in ASP.Net Core 2.0?

I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to resolve service for type
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager for ASP.Net Core 2.0

I have the following code:

```
  // add identity
  var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
  {
    // configure identity options
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
  });
  builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(AppRole), builder.Services);
  builder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
```

AppUser and AppRole are derived from IdentityUser and IdentityRole, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `AddIdentityCore()`. Have you tried the conventional `AddIdentity()`:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
    {
        ... 
    });
```

Comment: The code is taken from this: https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth/blob/master/src/Startup.cs . I'm not sure about the difference between AddIdentity and AddIdentityCore. The doc doesn't emphasize the difference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . I'll try using AddIdentity.

Comment: For me when I use `AddIdentity`, my API always redirects to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Fvalues` for unauthorized.  I don;t know why.  But when I use `AddIdentityCore` it doesn't

Comment: @DevEng If you compare the source code for AddIdentityCore https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Core/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs to AddIdentity https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs you will see that AddIdentity configures a lot more options, inlcuding the path to /account/login.